# Encrypting file as saved to disk

Tags: linux, encryption, samba

I was wondering if anyone could suggest a solution to the following challenge...

I've got a samba share on a linux server which is used as a shared drive on various windows PCs.

As a new file is saved (from a Microsoft PC) into the shared folder I would like the file to be encrypted, so when the file is saved to the disk the contents is already encrypted.

When the file is ready to be used the file could be decrypted and worked with.

Most of the solutions I can see in Linux are about mounting/unmounting a folder which is encrypted/decrypted in the process.  I'm interested in the encryption happening at the point the file is created.

Thanks in advance,

David

Comment: Do you mean writing to an encrypted volume?

Comment: I've had an experiment with eCryptFS but it's not really doing what I want.  It allows your to create a directory which can be mounted, have files added to it, and then unmounted.  While the directory is mounted the files are unencrypted, and while unmounted they are encrypted.  What I'm looking for is so that when a file is added to a folder (shared through Samba), it is encrypted as it's written to the disk, and then I can choose to decrypt a file at a time of my choosing.  No other users/processes would be able to access the content of the file in the Samba share. Thanks again in advance, D

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt the entire directory on the file server using e.g [eCryptFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECryptfs).  This is a standard package readily available on Ubuntu and other Linux distros which lets you encrypt specified files.  If you encrypt the entire directory on the server, then when writes come in, they will hit the disk already encrypted.  This does not encrypt the writes while in transit; for that you may want to enable the Samba option [`server signing = mandatory`](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9159/how-do-i-ensure-data-encryption-on-samba-transmission-on-nix-systems).

Comment: Thanks John, my aim is for the data to be encrypted as it's written to a new file in the Samba shared folder.  Once saved on disk if you were to open the file on the command line (or if the windows user were to open the file in the shared folder) it would be unreadable.  I then want an application to read the file and decrypt it.  I'll install eCrryptFs and have an experiment... thanks again David